# Change Password with firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, passwords

I have found documents (Manage Users ** Firebase Official docs) on how to change a password but not how to use a cloud function. The user.updatePassword(newPassword).then(() => { does not work for a cloud function. --> At lease that i am aware of...
My Goal if possible, is to pass the users userid and new password in a similar fashion to the above and have it change. Any examples or firebase doc's i might have missed would be great.
Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside Cloud Function you're using the Firebase Admin SDK to access Firebase Authentication, so you can [update the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) through that to set their password. From that link:

```
getAuth()
  .updateUser(uid, {
    password: 'newPassword',
  })
```

Comment: Genius!! Except in my case i have it set as admin.auth() - then i could uses the .updateUser(). Assome Thanks for the help Frank